# Code Issue in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python ,written simple code for one of my project

```
argv[1]={"configdatabase":"build1","oltpdatabase":"build1","paymentsdatabase":"build1","yccdatabase":"build1"}   
argv[2]=test.txt
```

Code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import json
    import ast
    from sys import argv
    data = argv[1];
    fileName=argv[2];
    data=data.replace("\\","")
    print (data)
    data = json.dumps(data)
    json_to_unicode = json.loads(data)
    unicode_to_dic = ast.literal_eval(json_to_unicode);
    print(type(unicode_to_dic));
    result_dic={};
    data="";
    for k,v in unicode_to_dic.iteritems():
      if v in result_dic.keys():
        data=data.join((result_dic[v],',',k));
        print (data)
        result_dic[v]=data

      else:
        result_dic[v]=k;

    for key,value in result_dic.iteritems():
      with open(fileName,'a') as the_file:
        the_file.write(key+':'+value+'\n')
```

Expected o/p `:build1:configdatabase,oltpdatabase,paymentsdatabase,yccdatabase`

But getting the output as below:

```
build1:oltpdatabase,yccdatabaseoltpdatabase,yccdatabase,oltpdatabase,yccdatabasepaymentsdatabaseoltpdatabase,yccdatabaseoltpdatabase,yccdatabase,oltpdatabase,yccdatabasepaymentsdatabase,oltpdatabase,yccdatabaseoltpdatabase,yccdatabase,oltpdatabase,yccdatabasepaymentsdatabaseconfigdatabase
```

Can someone Please help what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: you might consider making the `result_dic` a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects): `invert_data = defaultdict(list); 
[invert_data[k].append(v) for v, k in data.iteritems()]`, then `invert_data` looks like: `'build1': ['oltpdatabase', 'yccdatabase', 'paymentsdatabase', 'configdatabase']}`

Answer (score 0):

Unlike javascript, you don't use semi-colons at the end of python statements. That's not the issue, just a little tip. Try running this, the last print statement should print out what you need `':build1:configdatabase,oltpdatabase,paymentsdatabase,yccdatabase'`

The issue is you're taking a string value, adding k, and than appending that string value to the original string value. So it might look something like this.

Loop 1:

```
data = ''
result_dic[v] = {'build': 'configdatabase'}
```

Loop 2: So far so good, step 3 is where it gets hairy.

```
data = ''
data after join = 'configdatabase, oltpdatabase'
result_dic[v] = {'build': 'configdatabase, oltpdatabase'}
```

Loop 3:

```
data = 'configdatabase, oltpdatabase'
data after join = 'configdatabase, oltpdatabase, configdatabase, oltpdatabase, paymentsdatabase'
* Because you are joining data => 'configdatabase, oltpdatabase, paymentsdatabase' with result_dic[v] => 'configdatabase, oltpdatabase'
result_dic[v] = {'build': 'configdatabase, oltpdatabase, configdatabase, oltpdatabase, paymentsdatabase'}
```

I hope that makes sense. Good luck on your coding adventures !

```
# !/usr/bin/python
import json
import ast
from sys import argv

data = {
    "configdatabase": "build1",
    "oltpdatabase": "build1",
    "paymentsdatabase": "build1",
    "yccdatabase": "build1",
}

fileName = 'test.txt'
result_dic = {}

data_string = ""


for k, v in data.iteritems():
    if v in result_dic.keys():
        result_dic[v] += ',{0}'.format(k)
    else:
        result_dic[v] = k

print(result_dic)

for key, value in result_dic.iteritems():
    print('{}:{}\n'.format(key, value))
    with open(fileName, 'a') as the_file:
        the_file.write('{0}:{1}\n'.format(key, value))
```

Comment: Thanks .. But getting the Below error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sf.py", line 18, in <module>
    result_dic[v] += ',{}'.format(k)
ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: Hey Vatrivelkumar, I made a change to the format string, it shoudn't throw any fits now.